Fill chart with n bars but calculate the width of the bars to always keep the same gap
In ChartJS, I would like to distribute bars n over the length of the x axis. We can ignore the y axis for now as everything works as expected.
What I would like to achieve is, that the gap of the bars stays also the same, but the amount of bars determines how the width of each bar is.
So let's say I have 20 bars. Then considering the gap should be always the same, the bars have a width of 20 each. When I then reduce the amount of bars to let's say 5, I would like to keep the width of the gap the same but the remaining space created will be the bars width.
How can I do this?

might be related and related

@oelimoe does not look related to me, because in both examples it isn't about the full width, but left aligning?

use property barThickness: 'flex' so that chart.js will automatically adjust the thickness whenever data is added or removed from the chart.

@oelimoe I've tried that but it won't keep the gap the same.

have you tried to make the gap with padding options: {layout:{padding:{left: 50}}}

@oelimoe yup, does not work.

i believe the solution is to calculate the procent each bar needs to take but there are 2 values catagory size and bar size i advise to only calculate the bar and set the categorie on 1 i believe this is the only way i have searched alot of methods but couldnt find anything so for me the search ended

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to set the width of the gaps between bars and adapt everything else to that, there is no option for that, you'll have to compute the bar width, like barThickness <-- totalWidth / nBars - gap, fiddle. Of course, this might become interesting if there were multiple datasets.

@kikon it's you again :) with exactly what I needed. Mind providing an answer?

If you want to set the width of the gaps between bars and adapt
everything else to that, there is no specific option,
you'll have to compute the bar width using a formula based on the
total width (that can be obtained through the x scale, chart.scales.x),
the number of bars and the intended gap.
If there is only one dataset, the formula is as simple as:
barThickness <-- totalWidth / nBars - gap.
Demo snippet:


const nBars = 10,
   gap = 15; //px
const data = {
   labels: Array.from({length: nBars}, (_, i)=>String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0)+i)),
   datasets: [
      {
         label: 'Dataset 1',
         data: Array.from({length: nBars}, () => Math.random()*10),
      }
   ]
};

const config = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: data,
   options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      barThickness: function(context){
         const totalWidth = context.chart.scales.x.width;
         // there are nBars-1 gaps + half gap left + half gap right.
         return totalWidth / nBars - gap;
         // fun fact: if the result is negative, the option is ignored
      }
   },
};

new Chart("myChart", config);
<div style="height: 300px">
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



